# How to hide specific parts of a text without breaking the flow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a ErrorPage for my application, and I want to display the Stacktrace. I'd like to allow the user to hide or show especific parts of the stacktrace, like the namespace or the parameters, by checking or unchecking some checkboxes. So, I've put the parts I want to hide inside an span element, so i can hide it later using jquery and javascript.

The problem is to keep all elements in the same flow of text. I've set all my span elements do `display:inline-block`, what I've got is this:

```
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance
(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, 
RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)

System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow 
(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
```

The text inside parenthesis is in a separate span element, and it is the text i want to hide. As you can see, it can't start at one line and end on another. And what I'd like to achieve is bellow, but keeping the bold part in one span and the not bold part in a different span (or any other element that allows me to hide it separately):

```
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance (RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, 
Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, 
Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)

System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, 
Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Here's a thought: Never show error messages to your clients - it's a terrible user experience and can expose some very critical parts of your internal system.

Comment: use different css classes??

Comment: I'm not showing to the clients, this will a admin page only visible to us. I was just trying to make out lives easier.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've figured it out. when I tried to create a sample on jsfiddle, I discovered that if I use 'inline' instead of 'inline-block' it worked fine.